# Filename breaks when passed from Flask to Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

When I'm sending a filename as a variable from flask to jinja2 it breaks:

I'm using SQLAlchemy to store datas about projects (title, description and a picture to illustrate), and flask to send this data to a jinja2 page. This is the route:

```
@app.route('/projects')
def projects():
    project_matrix = listOfProjects()
    for i in range(0, len(project_matrix)):
            print(project_matrix[i][3])
    return render_template("projects.html", projects=project_matrix)
```

print(project_matrix[i][3]) shows in the terminal the name of the file of the picture for each project. This is what appears in the terminal when I reload the page

```
tethermc.jpg
graph.png
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2020 01:07:20] "GET /projects HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2020 01:07:20] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2020 01:07:20] "GET /static/img/uploads/%7B%7Bproject%5B3%5D%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/May/2020 01:07:20] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

and this is the template of the page:

```
  {% for project in projects %}
  <div class="project">
    <div class="projectTitle">
      {{ project[1] }}
    </div>
    <div class="projectHolding">
      <div class="projectDescription" type="html">
        {{ project[2] }}
      </div>
      <div class="projectImg">
        <img
          src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/uploads/'+'{{project[3]}}') }}"
          style="min-width: 100px; max-height: 300px;"
          alt="alt"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

When I load the page, the content isn't altered except the images that don't show up. When I inspect the elements (the image block) I see:

```
<img
    src="/static/img/uploads/%7B%7Bproject%5B3%5D%7D%7D"
    style="min-width: 100px; max-height: 300px;"
    alt="alt"
/>
```

There is `src="/static/img/uploads/%7B%7Bproject%5B3%5D%7D%7D"`
instead of `src="/static/img/uploads/ethermc.jpg"`
or `src="/static/img/uploads/graph.png"`

Do you have any idea of what's causing the problem ?

Comment: I can't test right now so I won't post an answer, but try:
`{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/uploads/'+project[3]) }}`

I think the extra {{ brackets aren't what you are after. once you are in the outer {{}}, you are in a "code block" in Jinja2.

Comment: It worked, thank you !!! You should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

`src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/uploads/'+'{{project[3]}}') }}"`.

First, there are single quotes around this part: `'{{project[3]}}'` which is causing those characters to be interpreted literally, rather than doing "what you wanted" and using the value in the project[3] variable. If you URL encode a curly brace, you get %7B or %7D, which might help you see how your incorrect filename was composed!

Second, you are "nesting" your curly braces, which isn't needed. The {{ }} next to project[3] are being interpreted literally as braces, which are being encoded to the %7B and %7D you are seeing in your final filenames. They are not needed here, because when you opened the "outside" curly braces, you are now in a code block, and everything in between is (basically) python code.

So the Python code you want to run is:

`url_for('static', filename = 'img/uploads/'+project[3])`

This means you should replace that line with:

`src="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'img/uploads/'+project[3]) }}"`